# IE, Firefox mismatch with div attributes

Tags: html, css

In Firefox, div takes the entire space available horizontally and starts from a new row if we don't give `float:left`, while in IE it doesn't.

Comment: That's...um...what it's supposed to do. IE is doing it wrong. What version of IE are you using?...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your doc type in the IE header?

e.g

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```